# why I face this error in R for optimization ? "There are variables in your environment that interfere with your defined model variables: x,y"

Tags: r, optimization

Hi everyone I am trying to run this code that belongs to [Here](https://github.com/dirkschumacher/ompr/) but I get this error:

```
"There are variables in your environment that interfere with your defined model variables: x,y. This can lead to unexpected behavior."
```

why is so ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)

result <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x, type = "integer") %>%
  add_variable(y, type = "continuous", lb = 0) %>%
  set_bounds(x, lb = 0) %>%
  set_objective(x + y, "max") %>%
  add_constraint(x + y <= 11.25) %>%
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk")) 
get_solution(result, x)
get_solution(result, y)
```

Comment: Taking the error message at face value, are you already using `x,y` for something else in your global environment? If so, and you don't need them, try removing them with `rm(x,y)`.

Comment: Oh yes I totally forget this thank you.